# Why are some answers CW, some not?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

See [this question about LaTeX in industry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/latex-in-industry). Some answers are community wiki, some not. What is the rationale / reason?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I made the question CW for a short while, but changed it back after a talk with Stefan Kottwitz. I thought this would also remove the CW from the existing answers, but this wasn't the case. I removed the CW from them now manually and recalculated the reputation of these users. However, I'm still not sure if they should be CW or not.

Comment: Perhaps see: [The Future of Community Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/).

Answer (score 7):

An important point to consider is that "there is no single *right* answer to this question" is probably not a sufficient cause for blanketing a discussion in community wiki flags. Doing so disregards the fact that there may be several "good answers" that take significant thought or effort to produce.

For example, it took me at least a half an hour of careful work to put together the example that I posted as an answer to [LaTeX in Industry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40728/17). Because of this, I was a bit miffed when the answer was flagged as community wiki without my consent as I missed any benefits of my hard work and unregistered users could add links that were tangental to the focus of my answer.